# Where to store data securely from a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, service

I'm writing a service using C# that is supposed to run on a Windows platform as the "local system". I can store small amounts of data in the registry, but if I want to store more data in a file, where do I place such file in? And also how to protect that data from a modification by users with lower access rights?

Comment: If you need security use a database.

Comment: @JeremyThompson And how will the database increase security???

Comment: @casperOne: "closed as not a real question" :))) OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General approach is to use [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class to encrypt the data, then store them anywhere on the disk where the application can (eg in a subfolder of LocalApplicationData special folder, whose location you can obtain using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` call).

Comment: ProtectedData class is a very good idea. Thanks for pointing it out. I read a little about it and it looks very easy to implement. I'm assuming I should be using it with `LocalMachine` DataProtectionScope from a local service, right?

Comment: @c00000fd yes, you should.

Comment: Note that `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` resolves to `C:\Windows\System32\Config\SystemProfile\AppData\Local` for a Windows Service. Writing under System32 may cause the service executable to be flagged and deleted by anti-virus programs.

Comment: @InteXX that's the problem of the buggy antivirus application then.

Comment: Not necessarily. An anti-virus program that flags an application that writes to the `%SystemRoot%` hierarchy is behaving properly. It's the individual developer's responsibility to avoid this design. For Windows Services, a better location is `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`.

Comment: @InteXX I am not arguing with you but with the logic of antivirus writers. The antivirus program assuming such thing is not behaving properly simply because there's no rule or demand not to write to the specified location.

Comment: Pardon me, I should have clarified my comment a bit better. I'm referring to general Windows development guidelines and best practices. We shouldn't be reading/writing in `%SystemRoot%`. In fact I believe that doing so can lead to an app being rejected by Microsoft's logo certification review.

Comment: @InteXX I think (this is a speculation, of course) that if we were not allowed to write to what LocalApplicationData points for services, the variable would point to a different place, no? "What's the use of the book without pictures or conversation", as Alice said.

Comment: For Windows Services, `CommonApplicationData` is the better choice. It resolves to `%ProgramData%`. We've been given just enough rope to hang ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Update to previous answer that may save some troubleshooting time to people using this solution (as I don't have enough reputation to comment):

For Local System Windows service account, `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`
may also be resolved to 
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local` instead of `C:\Windows\System32\Config\SystemProfile\AppData\Local`.

Using the already mentioned CommonApplicationData instead of LocalApplicationData does not bring this issue.

Information source: https://www.jamescrowley.net/2014/02/24/appdata-location-when-running-under-system-user-account/